# What does <0> mean with empty struct template?

Tags: c++, struct

I see a construction like this:

```
template<>
struct AliItemCalc< 0 >
{

}
```

What does zero mean?

EDIT before this there is a definition:

```
template <int N>
struct AliItemCalc
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned a1 = 4096;
    static constexpr unsigned s = AliItemCalc<N-1>::m;
    static constexpr unsigned v = a1 * (s & 0xFFFF);

public:
    static constexpr unsigned m = v;
};
```

Comment: This looks like a template specialization, though that would require a previous definition of a `AliItemCalc` class template

Comment: Likely, there is a previous definition `template <int N> struct AliItemCalc { ... };`. If so,  you should also post that.